# how to pass arguments to controller function from form action url using javascript

Tags: cakephp-2.0

a simple search program in which controllers function should be passed with arguments from form data using javascript.The search results should have pagination.

Comment: There is a cake [plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search) to do this and here is the bakery [article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/calin/2008/09/18/search-feature-to-cakephp-blog-example) to help you with that, though this is very old you might need to make some changes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it by GET method. you may get all parameters sent by GET method by following code:

```
$this->request->params;
```

if you are using named parameters then you may also use as following:

```
$this->request->named or $this->request['named']
```

pass these values in your search and get results. For pagination you may also pass page numbers and offsets and put them in paginator component